# Select first N elements from JSon

Tags: jsonpath

{"id1":"value1", "id2":"value2", "id3":"value3", "id4":"value4", "id5":"value5" ... etc.

$.* returns:

"value1",
"value2",
"value3",
"value4" ... etc

There are thousands values there. But I need only some specific number.

Is there a way to select them? 
I need something like $.[0:N]
but proper one.

Comment: use a for loop with the count of items you actually need...

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970709/json-element-selection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON element selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970709/json-element-selection)

Comment: I need to do this with JsonPath